# Converting __int64 to FileTime

Tags: windows, uint64, filetime

I have a code which is getting SystemTime as FileTime using

uint64 currentUtcFileTime;
GetSystemTimeAsFileTime((FILETIME*)&currentUtcFileTime);

Now I want to convert this uint64 back to FILETIME.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for long and finally got this solution -

FILETIME ftime;
__int64 i64;

*(__int64 *)&ftime = i64;

It worked well for me :)

Comment: `FILETIME` is 4 byte (`DWORD`) aligned structure. in general it address is not multiple 8x bytes. of course on x86/x64 this is not problem but possible on another platform is wrong. you need or separate assign every `DWORD` by using `LODWORD` and `HIDWORD` macros or force align it to 8 bytes like `union {
  __int64 align;
  FILETIME ft;
 };`